# ¿Cómo ocultar formulario y luego de un cierto tiempo redireccionar a otra página?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Integré la opción de cambiar la contraseña del usuario funciona perfectamente, el problema es que todos los datos quedan ahí mismo en el formulario.

Como puedo ocultar el formulario cuando reciba esta respuesta: ***¡Contraseña cambiada con éxito!*** y que luego de `x` segundo redirrecionar a otra página.

El código es el siguiente:

**Ajax**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var frm = $('#resetform');
    frm.submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = frm.serialize();
        formData += '&' + $('#submit_btn').attr('name') + '=' + $('#submit_btn').attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            success: function(data){
                $('#message').fadeIn();
                $('#message').html(data).delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#message').fadeIn();
                $('#message').html(textStatus).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
            }

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**form.php**

```
<form name="resetform" action="changepass.php" id="resetform" class="passform" method="post" role="form">
    <h3>Change Your Password</h3>
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php //echo $id_user; ?>" ></input>
    <label>Enter Old Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="old_password" id="old_password">
    <label>Enter New Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="new_password" id="new_password">
    <label>Confirm New Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control"  name="con_newpassword"  id="con_newpassword" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="password_change" id="submit_btn" value="Change Password" />
</form>
```

Teniendo en cuenta que solo  se debe cumplir aquella condición solamente si se recibe como respuesta de que todo es proceso fue exitoso, en este caso que el cambio de la contraseña fue exitoso.

Y que no vaya a redireccionar o ejecutar al recibir otro error de mensaje personalizado.

```
if (isset($_POST['password_change'])) {
    // Asignamos variables
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $old_password = $_POST['old_password'];
    $new_password = $_POST['new_password'];
    $con_password = $_POST['con_newpassword'];

    // comprobamos que las password coinciden
    if($con_password !== $new_password){
        echo "¡Las contraseñas no coinciden!";
        exit;
    }

    // Buscamos el usuario 
    $stmtUsers = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where username=? limit 1");
    $stmtUsers->bind_param("s", $username);
    // validamos consulta
    if(!$stmtUsers->execute()) {
        echo 'Error nose pudo ejecutar la consulta';
        exit;
    }
    //obtenemos el resultado
    if(!$result = $stmtUsers->fetch()){
        echo "Nombre de usuario incorrecto";
        exit;
    }

    // validamos password bd con la introducida
    if (!password_verify($old_password, $result['password'])) {
        echo '¡La contraseña no es válida!';
        exit;
    }

    // si llegamos hasta aquí todo esta en orden y actualizamos


    // cifrados la password antes de guardarla recuerda
    $hash = password_hash($new_password, CRYPT_BLOWFISH);

    $stmtUpdate = $con->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = ? WHERE `username` = ?");
    $stmtUpdate->bind_param("ss", $hash, $username);
    if($stmtUpdate->execute()){
        echo "¡Contraseña cambiada con éxito!";
    } else{
         echo "La contraseña no se pudo actualizar";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las dos opciones serían de la siguiente forma, dentro del `success`, aprovechando que ya tienes una variable que referencia al formulario `frm`

```
success: function(data){
   $(frm)[0].reset(); //Eliminar los valores en los input
   $(frm).hide();  // ocultar el formulario 
   // para redireccionar a otra página, sería setTimeout, 
   // o setInterval,la sintaxis es la misma 
   //como se recargará la página no habrá diferencia.
     setInterval(function(){ 
        location.href = 'google.com';
   },2000); // el 2000 es el tiempo en milisegundos,  2 segundos para el ejemplo
}
```

como recomendación, sería reemplazar el `success` por `done` para las devoluciones de éxito de las llamadas `ajax`.

Si desea validar los mensajes devueltos desde `PHP`, una opción sería no solo retornar el mensaje si no también un `status` para validar desde JavaScript, esto desde PHP ser haría con `json_encode` de la siguiente forma.

Para cambio exitoso

```
echo json_encode(['status'=> true, 'message'=>"¡La contraseña no es válida!"]);
```

Para cambios erróneos o errores en las validaciones

```
 echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=>"¡La contraseña no es válida!"]);
```

Desde JavaScript tendría en cuenta el `status` para saber si oculta o no el formulario.

```
$.ajax({
    type: frm.attr('method'),
    url: frm.attr('action'),
    data: formData,
})
.done(function(data) {
    let res = JSON.parse(data);
    if(res.status){ // si es true el estado
       $('#message').fadeIn();
       $('#message').html(res.message).delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
       $(frm).hide();
       setTimeout(function(){
        location.href = 'otrapágina';
        },2000);
    }
    else{ //caso contrario ejecutamos alguna otra opción

    }

})
.fail(function() {
    $('#message').fadeIn();
    $('#message').html(textStatus).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
})
```

Comment: Interesante +1, el redireccionamiento solo funciona cuando los datos son ingresados correctamente, o también se ejecuta cuándo existe un error, por ejemplo si introdujo mal la contraseña actual o si la contraseña no coincide con la repetición.

Comment: @IniDesing.com dicha validación debería hacerse desde PHP y desde ahí retornar los valores o validaciones, en realidad la pregunta solo se centró en ocultar formulario y redireccionar.

Comment: Entiendo pero el usuario SO, indicó que de un determinado mensaje de éxito se ejecute, tocaría preguntarle bien al SO.

Comment: @Dev.Joel Hola! Tiene razón IniDesing.com me preguntó lo mismo viendo los comentarios, todo caso actualicé mi pregunta gracias :)

Comment: @Fernando he actualizado mi respuesta para apoyar en ese detalle, espero le ayude . Saludos.

Comment: @Dev.Joel No entiendo muy bien amigo el único cambio que debo cambiar en mi código PHP es esto `echo '¡La contraseña no es válida!';` por esto `echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=>"¡La contraseña no es válida!"]);` no toca especificar nada más solo eso amigo :)

Comment: @Fernando con la clave status, validarás si es correcto o no, si debes cambiar los mensajes de echo con `json_encode`, además validar dentro del done _(res.status)_ para saber que hacer desde JavaScript. más nada

Comment: @Dev.Joel Comprendo, a que se refiere con esto, *validar dentro del done (res.status) para saber que hacer desde JavaScript* no entiendo yo no se mucho sobre este tema el código lo tengo porque lo he visto en un tutorial en la web :(

Comment: @Fernando solucionó su problema? ¿Qué parte de mi respuesta no está clara, así le explico mejor?

Comment: @Dev.Joel Como debe quedar el código final del `ajax` https://ideone.com/AlmV6W no me muestra ningún mensaje de error al cambiar la contraseña o al enviar incorrectamente los datos.

Comment: @Fernando no tienes nada en el `else`, ahí puedes hacer lo que desee con los mensaje de error, estarán también disponibles en `res.message`

Comment: @Dev.Joel Entiendo, pensé que los mensaje de error los hacía el `.fail` por favor amigo solo dígame para mostrar los mensajes de error, solo debo añadir esto: `$('#message').fadeIn();
       $('#message').html(res.message).delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);` en el `else`