# Conservar valor en un select html+php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy desarrollando un formulario sencillo con html, php y MySQL, el cual tiene validaciones de campos obligatorios, caracteres inválidos, etc.

**html**

```
               <?php include_once '../../includes/insert/insert_user.php'; ?>
               <h4 class="mb"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> REGISTRO USUARIO</h4>

               <span class="error"><?php echo $msg; ?></span>

                <form class="form-horizontal style-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label"><b>Nombre</b></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" minlength="3" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                       <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr; ?></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label"><b>Tipo de usuario</b></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                      <select class="form-control grey" id="tipo_usuario" name="tipo_usuario" value="<?php echo $tipo_usuario['tipo_usuario']; ?>">
                        <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                        <option value="Oficina">Oficina tecnica</option>
                        <option value="Personal">Personal</option>
                        <option value="Administrador">Administrador</option>
                      </select>
                      <span class="error">* <?php echo $tipo_usuarioErr; ?></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> GUARDAR</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
               </form>
```

**Php y mysql (insert_user.php)**

```
<?php

  include_once('../../includes/dbconfig.php');//mi conexion a la db
  $msg = "";

  $name $tipo_usuario = "";
  $nameErr = $tipo_usuarioErr = null;

  $valid = true;
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
     //validamos que los campos no sean vacíos y sean requeridos:
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "El nombre es requerido";
        $valid = false;
    } 
    else {

      $name = test_input($_POST['name']);
      // chequea que el nombre tenga letras y espacios
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
        $nameErr = "Solo se permiten letras y espacios, no acentos ni números";
        $valid = false;
      }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["tipo_usuario"])) {
      $tipo_usuarioErr = "El tipo de usuario es obligatorio";
      $valid = false;
    } else {
        $tipo_usuario = test_input($_POST["tipo_usuario"]);
    }

    if ($valid) {

      //Si pasa las validaciones, ejecuta el SQL
      $con->query("INSERT INTO users (name, tipo_usuario) VALUES ('$name','$tipo_usuario' )");
      echo "<script>alert('¡Usuario registrado con éxito!'); location.href='table_users.php';</script>";

    }

  }

  function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
  }

?>
```

Todo va bien en el insert, lo que ocurre es que cuando guardo y dejo el input name vacío se pierde la opción seleccionada en el "Select" y se reinicia como por defecto a la primera opción (Seleccione"), en cambio si lo hago dejando el select vacío no se pierde el valor del input name.

Comment: <option value="">Seleccione</option>..cambia por..<option selected disabled>Seleccione</option>.con ello queda preseleccionado

Comment: Al parecer al enviar los datos se vuelven a refrescar los valores de los inputs a su valor inicial, una opción seria realizar el envió por petición ajax.

Comment: Lo he sustituido y sigue resetenadose

Comment: A mi me parece que aquí el problema real es que estás programando un *código independiente* o sea, que hace *lo que le da la gana* y no lo que tú le digas cuando consideres que puede o debe hacerlo. En este caso concreto el criterio a seguir es muy sencillo: los datos no  pueden ser enviados mientras **las condiciones exigidas** se cumplan. Para eso hay que **controlar** el código, empezando por el lado del cliente (Javascript). [Mira este ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/189744/29967), el botón no se activa hasta que no se cumplan las condiciones necesarias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sustituye la sección de tu combo con esta solución que te propongo, son una serie de condicionales que te seleccionará el valor escogido en dicho listbox.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label"><b>Tipo de usuario</b></label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <select class="form-control grey" id="tipo_usuario" name="tipo_usuario">
            <option value="">Seleccione</option>
            <option value="Oficina" <?php if($tipo_usuario=="Oficina"){ echo "selected='selected'";}?>>Oficina tecnica</option>
            <option value="Personal" <?php if($tipo_usuario=="Personal"){ echo "selected='selected'";}?>>Personal</option>
            <option value="Administrador" <?php if($tipo_usuario=="Administrador"){ echo "selected='selected'";}?>>Administrador</option>
        </select>
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $tipo_usuarioErr; ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Además te hago las siguientes sugerencias:
>
> 1. Actualiza tu tipo de conexión a Mysqli o PDO: [Conexión a Base de datos MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)
> 2. Utiliza require o require_once en caso sea mandatorio un script para que detenga el programa en caso no estén tus escript de conexión o procesamiento.
> 3. Verifica la declaración de las variables
>      porque estan así: $name $tipo_usuario = ""; y decláralas así: $name = $tipo_usuario = "";

Answer (score 1):

una posible solucion es usar JavaScript:

```
<select id="opt_ciudades">
<option disabled>Seleccione</option>
<option value="1">Juarez</option>
<option value="2">Mendoza</option>
</select>
<script>
document.getElementById('opt_ciudades').selectedIndex =0;
</script>
```

Si te fijas establezco el selected mediante el index en este caso es "0" para establecer predefinido el primer option.