# Como Verifico una variable php esta vacia? Null

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin

Este seria el codigo, necesit saber como verifico si la variable esta vacio o no.
(comentarios donde necesito la verificacion)

```
<?php include("coneccion.php");
/***************   SQL    ******************/
    @$buscar=$_POST["buscar"];
if($buscar){
    $ceda = $_POST["ceda"];
    $sql ="select * from cliente where cedula ='$ceda'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $total=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($total){
        while($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $nomba = $registro["nombre"];
            $direca = $registro["direccion"];
            $tela = $registro["telefono"];
        }

    }
    else{       echo "<script>alert('No Existe el Cliente');</script>"; }
}
@$boton2=$_POST["boton2"];
if($boton2){
$ceda= $_POST["cedu"];
$nomba=$_POST["nombn"];
$direca=$_POST["direcn"];
$tela=$_POST["teln"];
/*Verificacion de cada campo, $ceda, nomba, direca, tela*/
$sql ="select * from cliente where cedula ='$ceda'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$total=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($total){
    $sql= "update cliente set nombre='$nomba', direccion='$direca', telefono='$tela' where cedula='$ceda'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $nomb="";
    $direc="";
    $tel="";
    echo "<script>alert('Cliente Actualizado');</script>";
    }
    else{
    echo "<script>alert('Error en la Base de Datos');</script>";

    }
}

/***************formulario******************/

echo"<form action=index.php#services method=post>";
echo"<table id='table2'><tr>";
    echo"<th>Cedula del Cliete a Actuaizar</th>";
    echo"<td><input type=text name=ceda size=10 value=\" ".@$ceda." \"></td>";
    echo"<td><input type=submit name=buscar value=Buscar>";
    echo"</td>";
echo"</table>";
echo"</form>";

echo"<form action=index.php#services method=post>";
echo"<table id='table2'><tr>";
    echo"<th colspan=2><br>Datos Actuales</th>";
    echo"<th colspan=2><br>Datos Nuevos</th></tr>";
    echo"<th>Nombre</th>";
    echo"<td><input type=text name=nomb size=20 value=\" ".@$nomba." \"></td><td>/*if nombn es nulo...*/<input type=text name=nombn size=20 ></td>";
    echo"</tr><tr>";
    echo"<th>Direccion</th>";
    echo"<td><input type=text name=direc size=25 value=\" ".@$direca." \"></td><td>/*if direcn es nulo...*/<input type=text name=direcn size=25 ></td>";
    echo"</tr><tr>";
    echo"<th>Telefono</th>";
    echo"<td><input type=text name=tel size=15 value=\" ".@$tela." \"></td><td>/*if teln es nulo...*/<input type=text name=teln size=15 ></td>";
    echo"</tr><tr><td colspan=2>";
    echo"<input type=submit name=boton2 value=Actualizar Cliente>";
        echo"<input type=hidden name=cedu size=10 value=".@$ceda.">";
    echo"</tr>";
echo"</table>";
echo"</form>";
?>
```

Comment: Validar que una variable php este vacia o no

Comment: También se explica eso en el apartado [**Código PHP**  de la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/189744/29967) a la pregunta indicada más arriba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurre que lo puedes resolver en el front de tu aplicacion usando javascript o jquery.

Si usas javascript puedes usar la siguiente sentencia:

```
var valor = document.getElementById("id de tu input").value;
if(valor !== '')
{  //ejecuto algo CUANDO ES NO VACIO }
else
{  //ejecuto otra acción CUANDO ES VACIO }
```

Tambien, puedes usar `document.getElementByName("name de tu input")` si le asignaste un name al input.

Otra forma, por javascript puede ser accediendo al input como

```
var valor = $("#id de tu input").val()
if(valor !== '')
{  //ejecuto algo cuando no es vacio }
else
{  //ejecuto otra acción CUANDO ES VACIO }
```

Tambien, puedes usar la propiedad `.length`de la siguiente forma:

```
var tamanio = $("#id de tu input").val().length()
if(tamanio === 0) { //el input es vacio }
```

Espero que te sea util. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Las validaciones de datos introducidos pueden realizarse en 2 partes:

- Del lado del cliente
- Del lado del servidor

**Del lado del cliente:** significa que en tu html has colocado código con javascript que realiza las validaciones de los datos introducidos, en este caso por ej si el campo está vacío no deja que se envíe el formulario. Aunque es una opción bastante usada pues evita que el servidor procese peticiones incorrectas optimizando el uso de CPU, no es una opción fiable pues el javascript podría desactivarse en el navegador haciendo que tales validaciones no se apliquen, o incluso podría alguien lanzar una petición con otra herramienta para saltar tales controles.

**Del lado del servidor:** Significa que en la tecnología de servidor utilizada (para tu caso PHP), se procesa la petición y se validan si los datos que llegan cumplen con las condiciones necesarias, como por ej que no esté el campo vacío, esta es la opción más segura, pues independientemente desde donde provenga la petición o quien la genere no se podrían saltar los controles, la desventaja es que el servidor tendría siempre que procesar la petición aún si esta es válida o no, lo que implica un alto consumo de recursos del servidor.

Y entonces? Qué hacer? Lo mejor es implementar las 2 opciones, puede tomar un poco más de tiempo pero por una parte en situación normal evitará que el servidor procese peticiones inválidas, y en una situación anormal evitaría posibles ataques a tu sitio o aplicación web.